# apk parse error on phone but works well on emulator

Tags: android, emulation

My application runs well on emulator but when I run on device it gives error parsing the package!!

what changes should be made to make it work on device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your minSdkVersion value in Android-Manifest.xml is more than your phone API level. reduce it to be installable on your phone.
Find appropriate API level for Android version of your phone here:
1.5 : API level 3
1.6 : API level 4
2.0 : ApI level 5
2.0.1: API level 6
2.1: API level 7
2.2: API level 8
2.3: API level 9
2.3.3: API level 10
3.0: API level 11
3.1: API level 12
3.2: API level 13
4.0: API level 14
4.0.3: API level 15
4.1: API level 16

Answer (score 0):

Installation can give the specified error in following cases:

```
Name of the package is changed after signing: Use the exact name as the signed package is (instead, adjust the name in Manifest)
Package is compiled against on higher API level: Correct the API level in Manifest file
Package is executed from SD-card: Run (install) the apk -file from phones memory OR use adb command to install it
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are compiled against a higher API level. Go to your Manifest file and change this line

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="VERSION_NUMBER_YOU_USING"
```

to

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
```

and see if you can install the apk on your device.